# MS-SQL query time out expired error ( in-case of multi server and multi DB infrastructure )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

We are having multi server and multi DB instances in EC2. In one of the Server we have the Main DB(Master DB), but in other servers we have only the Transaction DB's. We are using SQL linked server to connect everything.

Initially there was no problem with my infrastructure. But now as the data load increased, am often getting Time Out expired error even for an normal select query.

Its not for all the processes. If there are 500 processes running in a particular server, in that at-least 200 processes are throwing this Time out expired error.

Recently, I moved all my servers into VPC.

## Note:

All my queries will be running only from Master DB because only master DB knows what transaction DB is connected to respective transaction requests. All EC2 instances are in the same region.

Is there a solution for my problem ( time out error exception ). Kindly help me with your suggestions. This is really turning out into an critical business affecting issue.

## Error Msg:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Since it worked fine before and started to fail with as load increased, sounds like you are running out or resources (mostly hardware). There are two things to do:

1) Buy more hardware;
2) Tunning your queries to do more work with less (hardware).

The first thing is (maybe) cheaper. To tuning your DB it ill take a lot of time for learning and test out whatever you learn.
I suggest you to get the hard way and try to optimize your queries/isolation level/schema etc.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable post